# assign itemsSource of DataGrid inside usercontrol in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I am quite new to wpf so maybe I am missing something obvious here. I have found a similar question in stackoverflow and tried the solution (which is implemented in the code given below) but was not able to get it work. The link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904510/how-to-access-itemssource-property-of-a-datagrid-defined-in-usercontrol-from-mai). Let me explain the problem. I am working with framework 2010.

I have a usercontrol which contains 1 datagrid and 3 buttons. The xaml of the same is as below.

```
<UserControl x:Class="RadarControls.RadarDataGrid"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RadarControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Name="myGrid" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"></DataGrid>

    <Button Content="Add" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" Margin="0,2,2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="btnAdd" Width="100" />
    <Button Content="Delete" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,2,2,0" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="btnDelete" Width="100" />
    <Button Content="Save" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" Margin="0,2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="btnSave" Width="100" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The xaml of my window where i am using this usercontrol is as below

```
<Window x:Class="RadarStudio.Users"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:RadarControls;assembly=RadarControls"
    xmlns:vm='clr-namespace:RadarViewModel.Users;assembly=RadarViewModel'
    Title="Users" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid >
    <ctrls:RadarDataGrid Name="grid1" DataContext="{Binding str}"></ctrls:RadarDataGrid>
</Grid>
```

My window code behind is as follows

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace RadarStudio
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Users.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Users : Window
    {
        public Users()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //this.DataContext = this;

            str.Add("dhaval");
            str.Add("ravinder");
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> str = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
}
```

I tried so many things but I am not able to get the strings on my grid.

Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Samar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to be a silly mistake but when I initialized the observable collection before InitializeComponent call then it started to show the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can only bind to public properties! Make `str` as property.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx): `The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must be public properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected, private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base implementation.`

`You cannot bind to public fields.`

Answer (score 0):

As Zabavsky mentioned, WPF binding works with properties of an object, but not fields.

Try changing str to property:

```
public partial class Users : Window
{
    public Users()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        str = = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        str.Add("dhaval");
        str.Add("ravinder");
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> str { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

I just checked for your sample data **it worked fine** i don't test further.

**Check thoroughly....**

I Just Modified Your Code, and Posted below.

```
<UserControl x:Class="RadarControls.RadarDataGrid"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"  >
     <!--xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RadarControls"-->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid Name="myGrid" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  AutoGenerateColumns="True"></DataGrid> //Data Grid Is Modified

        <Button Content="Add" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" Margin="0,2,2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="btnAdd" Width="100" />
        <Button Content="Delete" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,2,2,0" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="btnDelete" Width="100" />
        <Button Content="Save" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" Margin="0,2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="btnSave" Width="100" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The xaml of my window where you are supposed to use this usercontrol

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace RadarControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for RadarDataGrid.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class RadarDataGrid : UserControl
    {
        public RadarDataGrid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public DataGrid RadarGrid//New Public Class is added
        {
            get { return myGrid; }
        }
    }
}
```

The xaml of window  where you are supposed to use  this usercontrol

```
<Window x:Class="RadarStudio.Users"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Users" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid >
        <!--xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:RadarControls;assembly=RadarControls"
        xmlns:vm='clr-namespace:RadarViewModel.Users;assembly=RadarViewModel'-->
        <Grid Name="Dggrid"> </Grid>//New Grid is added as a place holder
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

window code behind is as follows

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using RadarControls;

namespace RadarStudio
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Users.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Users : Window
    {
        RadarDataGrid rg = new RadarDataGrid();//Object of user control
        List<UserList> List = new List<UserList>();// It will be your item source
        UserList ListItem;
        public Users()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //this.DataContext = this;
            ListItem = new UserList();
            ListItem.UserName = "dhaval";//Adding First Item
            List.Add(ListItem);
            ListItem = new UserList();
            ListItem.UserName = "ravinder";//Adding Second
            List.Add(ListItem);
            rg.RadarGrid.ItemsSource = List;//Assigned Itemsource

            Dggrid.Children.Add(rg);
        }
    }

/*This Class is need to store user information, you can include users additional details 
(if needed) by creating corresponding Properties*/
    public class UserList
    {
        string userName;

        public string UserName
        {
            get { return userName; }
            set { userName = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Window has not Datacontext, and when your are binding str not found.  Modify xaml :

```
<Window x:Class="RadarStudio.Users"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:RadarControls;assembly=RadarControls"
xmlns:vm='clr-namespace:RadarViewModel.Users;assembly=RadarViewModel'
Title="Users" Height="300" Width="300"
Name="root">

<Grid >
    <ctrls:RadarDataGrid Name="grid1" DataContext="{Binding Path=str, ElementName=root}"/>
</Grid> </Window>
```

And set str as Property

```
public partial class Users : Window
{
    public Users()
    {
        str = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.DataContext = this;

        str.Add("dhaval");
        str.Add("ravinder");
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> str { get; set; }
}
```